# java script capitalize letters in a input form

Tags: javascript, capitalize

Hey guys what am I doing wrong here?? I'm sorry if this has been posted before, but I couldn't find a good example with a form input.

Thank you.

I really don't understand why output.value.toUpperCase() doesn't work, or toUpperCase(output.value) wouldn't work.

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>

    <h1 id="title">Capitalize a String</h1>
        <form>
          <input type="text" id="entry" placeholder="Enter a string to be capitalized">
        </form>

        <h1 id="title">Output</h1>

        <form>
          <input type="text" id="output" placeholder="Output">
        </form>

        <div id="goBtn">
          <h1 id="goBtnText">
            GO
          </h1>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>



var goBtn = document.getElementById('goBtn');
var entry = document.getElementById('entry');
var output = document.getElementById('output');

goBtn.addEventListener('click', capitalizeStr);

function capitalizeStr () {
   output.value = entry.value;

  return output.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform

Comment: return output.value=output.value.toUpperCase();

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do

```
function capitalizeStr () {
   output.value = entry.value.toUpperCase();
}
```

Calling `output.value.toUpperCase()` does not change the `output.value` property, it just returns a new string (and the value `return`ed by an event listener is ignored).